# Can I use the $language variable in a Drupal 6 template file?

Tags: 6, theming, i18n-l10n

Is it correct to use the `$language` variable to make conditions in the page-front.tpl.php?
Is `if ($language == 'es')` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables that are usable in a page template are visible in the source code of [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6). The template file you are referring to has the variable `$language`, which is a copy of the global `$language`, where `$language->direction` has instead the values "rtl" and "ltr."
The content of `$language` is an object with the following properties:

- 'language'
- 'name'
- 'native'
- 'direction'
- 'enabled'
- 'plurals'
- 'formula'
- 'domain'
- 'prefix'
- 'weight'
- 'javascript'

The line of code you wrote needs to be written as `if ($language->language == 'es')`.